# Handling multiple instances of Click CliRunner

Tags: python, testing, concurrency

I had a project that used the [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/) library for CLI commands. For testing purposes, I had created a fixture that looked like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", name="runner")
def fixture_cli_runner():
    """Fixture for CLIRunner."""
    return CliRunner()
```

This worked well as I only had one CLI within my repository. However, as they often do, scope has expanded so I now have to add a second CLI. My directory structure now looks like this:

```
command_one:
- command_one.py
command_two:
- command_two.py
```

where each of these has the a structure similar to this (this one is for `command_two.py`):

```
@click.group()
def main():
    """Command two CLI."""
    configure_log()


@main.command
def do_thing():
    """Do a thing."""
    pass
```

Unfortunately, the shortcomings of `CliRunner` mean that these tests consistently fail because state is overwritten in between tests, even though I have it scoped at the module level. For example, I have the following test in `test_command_two.py`:

```
def test_main(cli_runner):
    """Test the main function."""
    result = cli_runner.invoke(command_two.main)
    assert result.exit_code == 0
    print(result.output)
    assert (
        result.output
        == """Usage: main [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Command two CLI.

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  do-thing  Do a thing.
"""
    )
```

However, this fails and prints the message shown for `command_one.py`.

Clearly, the issue is that `CliRunner` is failing to maintain separate state for each of the CLIs I'm testing because they're being tested in parallel. Does anyone know of a workaround for this or a way to ensure packages are tested serially?